# Setting ContentRoot and WebRoot in ASP.NET Core at runtime (e.g. using a config file)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core Website self hosted within a Windows Service that gets installed on multiple machines. I don't want to hardcode the `WebRoot` directory or depend on its relative path inside `ContentRoot` `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`. I would like it to be configurable using a json configuration file for example, so I tried the following:

In Program.cs:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
host.RunAsService();
```

In Startup.cs:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
        env.WebRootPath = Configuration["webroot"];
    }
```

My appsettings.json looks like this:

```
{
  "webroot": "C:\\path\\to\\my\\custom\\webroot",
  "Logging": {
     "IncludeScopes": false,
     "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "System": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information"
     }
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't work. I would like to know what the right way is.

**EDIT**:

Here are the contents of `project.json`

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {}
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install" ],
    "prepare": ["webpack -p"],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you just need to put the env.WebRootPath before the builder.build() command so that it is included with the path you want to set.

Comment: This actually causes a null pointer exception. Reading keys from the configuration (`env.WebRootPath = Configuration["webroot"];`) object before building it causes the service to crash.

Comment: Does it work correctly when you hard code the path for at least one instance of the service?

Comment: It only works correctly when I hard code the webroot directory on the `WebHostBuilder` object in `Program.cs` using `.useWebRoot("<hardcoded path>")`

Comment: Can you post contents of your project.json file?

Comment: @Ignas Edited the question and added it